# Generate a Random Value between Two Limits

Tags: node-editor

How do you generate a random value from between two values of my choosing? So, for example, I want to generate random evenly distributed values from between, say -.5 and 7? what is the node setup to achieve this?

Thanks
JK

Comment: You mean "random" for each object? Using the Object info node and some math or "random" through the same object (ex: per face, per vertex..)?

Comment: So you mean "random"... what? What kind of node editor are you interested in? Could you make an example of usage of this random value?

Answer (score 3):

Duarte Farrajota Ramos came up with a better suggestion with the Object Info > Random value.  Then you just run it into a standard linear interpolation function `t*(a-b)+b`.  If you're feeding in random numbers 0..1 it does not matter whether a<b or a>b.  You still get a value in the range a..b.

[image]

The extra nodes at the bottom with the vector coordinate going into the noise texture will give you a solid color, but it will be identical on all objects that use that material.

Comment: http://imgur.com/b8mputo

Comment: Hi Mutant Bob - thanks - not quite right - can you see my imgur above? the material is then noisy. it should be a solid colour randomly chosen from within the wavelength limits - side question: shouldn't you subtract the small number from the large one?

Comment: @JKCapeTown Adding a Normal node connected to the Vector input of the noise texture will make the color solid.

Comment: Use the same node setup, instead of a *Noise* texture as input use the *Random* socket of a *Object Info* node